# Android Wear system updates origin

Tags: android-wear

Are the system updates for Android Wear coming from Google or from the watches vendor?

I've tried to Google this information, but I found nothing on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The updates for Android Wear OS are released by Google.

As depicted in the image below. Find the source of image [here](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/139007-android-wear-2-0-what-s-new-in-the-major-software-update-for-watches)

[image: Android Wear 2.0 release]

Hope this satisfies your query.

Comment: Maybe the vendor decides how it'll be. I just found this article about Nixon releasing AW2 to their watches :/ https://www.androidheadlines.com/2017/03/nixon-says-android-wear-2-0-will-hit-mission-march.html . OMG this is all so confusing